# Google Oauth2 GoogleIdTokenVerifier connection refused error?

Tags: spring-boot, api, google-api, google-oauth

I am using  GoogleIdTokenVerifier to verify the token in my spring boot rest service for verify the user.It is working fine on development environment but getting following `connection refused` error on production server.

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:264)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:148)
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1012)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.refresh(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:172)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GooglePublicKeysManager.getPublicKeys(GooglePublicKeysManager.java:140)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:174)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify(GoogleIdTokenVerifier.java:192)
    at in.cdac.iaf.security.AuthorizationFilter.getAuthentication(AuthorizationFilter.java:112)
    at in.cdac.iaf.security.AuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthorizationFilter.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.access$000(ErrorPageFilter.java:66)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter$1.doFilterInternal(ErrorPageFilter.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter.doFilter(ErrorPageFilter.java:121)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:789)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Nio2Endpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(Nio2Endpoint.java:1694)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Code of Authorization filter is:

```
 String email = null;
     String  remoteAddr="";
     
        if (req != null) {
            remoteAddr = req.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
            if (remoteAddr == null || "".equals(remoteAddr)) {
                remoteAddr = req.getRemoteAddr();
            }
        }
        logger.info("authorization Request:"+remoteAddr);
     String authorizationHeader=req.getHeader(env.getProperty("authorization.token.header.name"));
    
     if(authorizationHeader==null) {
         logger.info("Request with empty Header from Client:"+remoteAddr);
         return null;
     }
    
     String token=authorizationHeader.replace(env.getProperty("authorization.token.header.prefix")+" ","");
     
     String CLIENT_ID=env.getProperty("authorization.client-id");
     
 try {
     
     final JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
    
     // HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
     HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
     logger.info("Transport created and token has been sent");
    
     GoogleIdTokenVerifier verifier = new GoogleIdTokenVerifier.Builder(httpTransport, jacksonFactory)
               // Specify the CLIENT_ID of the app that accesses the backend:
            .setAudience(Collections.singletonList(CLIENT_ID))
             // Or, if multiple clients access the backend:
            // .setAudience(Arrays.asList(CLIENT_ID_1, CLIENT_ID_2, CLIENT_ID_3))
            //.setIssuer("https://accounts.google.com")
            .build();
         // (Receive idTokenString by HTTPS POST)
         String idTokenString = token;
        // System.out.println("Token is: "+token);
    
    GoogleIdToken idToken = verifier.verify(idTokenString);
    logger.info("Authentication respose Received "+idToken);
    
    if (idToken != null) {
        Payload payload = idToken.getPayload();
        
        
        // Print user identifier
        String userId = payload.getSubject();
        
        // Get profile information from payload
        email = payload.getEmail();
        boolean emailVerified = Boolean.valueOf(payload.getEmailVerified());
        String name = (String) payload.get("name");
        String pictureUrl = (String) payload.get("picture");
        String locale = (String) payload.get("locale");
        String familyName = (String) payload.get("family_name");
        String givenName = (String) payload.get("given_name");
        String client_id=(String) payload.get("aud");
        //String issuedAt=(String) payload.get("iat");

        //System.out.println("issuedAt:"+issuedAt);
        
        // Use or store profile information
        logger.info("User logged in as: "+email);
        // ...in this section

    //check Client id is right or not
        if(client_id.equals(CLIENT_ID)) {
            //code here
        }
        else {
            logger.info("User requested by wrong client id:"+email);
            logger.warn("Unauthorized request from user id:"+email);
             return null;
        }
        
        
    } else {
        logger.warn("Unauthorized request by client ID:"+remoteAddr);
        //System.out.println("Invalid ID token.");
        return null;
    }
}

catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    logger.warn(e.getLocalizedMessage());

    return null;
}
     
     if(email==null) {
         return null;
     }
    
    
    logger.info("User Authenticated: "+email);
     return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email,null,new ArrayList<>());
 }
```

Which links should i  whitelist on my production server environment?